# Axioms of one-dimension geometry in Hilbert's style

Tags: geometry, foundations, axiomatic-geometry

Do somewhere full axiomatic system axioms of one-dimensional geometry presented in Hilbert's "Foundations of Geometry" style? (With incidence, order, congruence and continuity axioms, as described in existing systems for three- and two-dimensional cases.)

Comment: The incidence axioms would fail, since they imply (or state) the existence of three non-colinear points. Besides, the real line is pretty well-described using other languages, like analysis or algebra.

Comment: In this case there will be at least axioms about relation "lie between", why it will fail? One of this question goals is just to figure out the relative prettiness of one of this languages. Let mean it as math foundations and logical task.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the lower dim axiom (saying that there are three non collinear points) from Hilbert's or Tarski's axioms and add an upper dim axiom saying that all points are collinear, I guess you obtain an axiom system for one-dimentional geometry.

You can find axiomatization of the order relation on a line in Section 2 of the following paper by Victor Pambuccian:
The axiomatics of ordered geometry: I. Ordered incidence spaces.